# How do i find out programmatically if the wpf user control has been displayed

Tags: wpf

How do i find out programmatically if the wpf user control has been displayed? I cannot use the Loaded event because when the Loaded event gets fired the view is not displayed. I am looking for something when the view has been displayed.

Answer (score 2):

ContentRendered may be what you want..

Though its not available for the UserControl itself - but will be for the ultimate visual parent such as the Window.. Though MSDN would dispute what you say about the Loaded event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx): "Occurs when the element is laid out, rendered, and ready for interaction."

Comment: Wow; that's the shortest possible answer, given the rules of SO... :)

Comment: :) its a shame I updated it but turns out it wasnt so starightforward :(